# Low disk performance in Ubuntu VM on Azure

Tags: azure

I was evaluating Azure and it appears the Ubuntu VM I created has unexpectedly low disk performance. I noticed this because the database import took much longer compare to another Rackspace VM I'm using. And I'm not sure whether there is any important configurations that I missed or is it just I'm looking at the disk performance in the wrong way. Here are my tests and the results:

**Standard A1 VM (1 core, 1.75GB memory, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)**

- **sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdb**

> Timing cached reads:   6892 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3451.31 MB/sec
>
> Timing buffered disk reads:  40 MB in  3.37 seconds =  11.88 MB/sec

- **sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/sdb**

> Timing O_DIRECT disk reads:  46 MB in  3.74 seconds =  12.29 MB/sec

- **sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test bs=8k count=200000; sudo rm -f /mnt/test**

> 1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 246.32 s, 6.7 MB/s

As comparison, my other VM on **Rackspace (4 vCPU, 1GB memory, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)** has the following results:

- **sudo hdparm -tT /dev/xvda**

> Timing cached reads:   5960 MB in  1.99 seconds = 2990.32 MB/sec
>
> Timing buffered disk reads: 200 MB in  3.05 seconds =  65.66 MB/sec

- **sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/xvda**

> Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 162 MB in  3.12 seconds =  52.00 MB/sec

- **sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=8k count=200000; sudo rm -f test**

> 1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 13.7139 s, 119 MB/s

Although the Azure VM has better cached read performance, its disk read (both buffered and direct) is quite slow, and disk write (or copy) is way worse. As Linux VM on Azure does not have swap file configured by default, I manually created a 5GB swap file (on /dev/sdb) but it does not seem to help.

Then I did one more around of testing on Azure using a **Standard D3 VM (4 cores, 14GB memory, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)**. When executing the commands above on /dev/sdb the performance was amazing, I guess because of local SSD? However when I attach an additional disk to that D3 VM and run the same commands on the newly created /dev/sdc partition (ext4), the results are just as bad as the A1 instance.

Not sure if this is the best way to test disk performance in Linux. But it is pretty noticeable that the Azure VM is much slower when restoring database backup. Microsoft Azure support page suggests that we could ask question here with the "azure" tag, so ... Any comments is welcomed.

Comment: Good question for ServerFault (stackoverflow is specifically for programming questions). While you're busy moving this question over, consider the fact that you're attaching the same type of disk to both D3 and A1: Blob-backed vhd. And each blob tops out at 500 IOPS. This is unrelated to the VM itself (aside from network bandwidth). Also look up Azure Premium Storage.

Comment: @David Makogon Thanks. I'm checking out the Premium Storage right now, just signed up for the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D series are SSD based. Your /mnt or /mnt/resource on an A would also be SSD based and local to the server, but is not persistent. Cloud vendors have guidance on setting up striping or RAID0 (or 10) to increase IOPS. For Azure, I suggest taking a look at [this guide](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-optimize-mysql-perf/) that is designed for MySQL but covers from the disks up.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I followed that guide and set up a RAID0 on my server. The improvement is pretty noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the disk that I attached to the Standard D3 VM earlier, then followed the same process and attached a new one. Somehow the newly attached disk has much better performance as showing below
**Standard D3 VM (4 cores, 14GB memory, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)**

- **sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sdc**

> Timing cached reads:   13054 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6546.15 MB/sec
>
> Timing buffered disk reads:  68 MB in  3.01 seconds =  22.57 MB/sec

- **sudo hdparm -t --direct /dev/sdc**

> Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 98 MB in  3.03 seconds =  32.35 MB/sec

- **sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test bs=8k count=200000; sudo rm -f /mnt/test**

> 1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 1.5689 s, 1.0 GB/s

Not exactly sure why. But my problem does not exist any more. Therefore closing this question.